# How to setup elasticsearch on Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, elasticsearch, searchkick

I've implemented elasticsearch/searchkick on my app and it works on development. My resources for the elasticsearch/searchkick implementation is GoRails and I installed elasticsearch successfully. But when I pushed it on Heroku, it gave me the error:

> "We're sorry, but something went wrong."

I did heroku logs and the errors are:

> "Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 16ms (Searchkick: 8.0ms |
>   ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)"

and

> "Faraday::ConnectionFailed (Connection refused - connect(2) for
>   "localhost" port 9200):"

Comment: You have installed the add-on on heroku dashboard? right? https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bonsai#installing-the-add-on

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Please try this .................

```
Searchkick uses ENV["ELASTICSEARCH_URL"] for the Elasticsearch server. This defaults to http://localhost:9200.
Heroku
```

Choose an add-on: SearchBox, Bonsai, or Elastic Cloud.

**# SearchBox**

```
heroku addons:create searchbox:starter
heroku config:set ELASTICSEARCH_URL=`heroku config:get SEARCHBOX_URL`
```

**# Bonsai**

```
heroku addons:create bonsai
heroku config:set ELASTICSEARCH_URL=`heroku config:get BONSAI_URL`
```

**# Found**

```
heroku addons:create foundelasticsearch
heroku config:set ELASTICSEARCH_URL=`heroku config:get FOUNDELASTICSEARCH_URL`
```

Then deploy and reindex:

```
heroku run rake searchkick:reindex CLASS=Product
```

Please refer this documentation https://github.com/ankane/searchkick#deployment for more information.
Hope this will work for you. Thanks!

Comment: thank you @Akshay. but instead of heroku run rake searchkick:reindex CLASS=Product, I run instead heroku run rails searchkick:reindex:all CLASS=Product so that my autocomplete works

Comment: @Jeramae : Are you using Rails 5 right? If yes then yes you need to run command like this `heroku run rails searchkick:reindex:all CLASS=Product`